# Disable Access-Control-Allow-Origin from apache or htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

In my local machine when I try to send a request via ajax using cross domain the request doesn't complete. I added this options to my .htaccess file:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://accepted-domain"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

After that, everything worked just fine but when I uploaded this to my cPanel server the request didn't complete. 
However, if I remove these lines from the .htaccess file everything works just fine.

**The question is:** How to disable this Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my cPanel host to define it with the domain I want to accept only ?

**UPDATED**
When I sent the request on my cPanel hosting the response was this message:

```
Failed to load http://receiver-domain.com/create.php: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://sender-domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Which means the Access-Control-Allow-Origin has been set somewhere else.

Comment: try to find the .htaccess file in your project may there you have implemented it.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz no I deleted the .htaccess file and the project is completely clean